# Network Manager Startup Hook

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, domain-name-system, startup

How to add a line like:

```
    search somesuffix.com
```

to `/etc/resolv.conf` on Network Manager startup in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager uses dhclient for DHCP leases, and you would be better off using dhclient hooks to change /etc/resolv.conf

You're probably running dhcp3-client on Ubuntu, I think it's the default with 8.10 and 9.04 at least.

If you are, your configuration file is in /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf

You can specify, per-interface modifications to /etc/resolv.conf

e.g.

```
interface "wlan0" {
    supersede domain-name "int.domain.com domain.com";
}
```

That will generate an /etc/resolv.conf with:

```
domain int.domain.com
search int.domain.com domain.com
```

man 5 dhclient.conf for more info.